# How can spring using @Resource to register a bean

Tags: java, spring

I am studying someone's code in my company, and found a strange code, but don't know how it work.

The code looks like this

```
interface A {...}

interface B {...}

class MyClass implements A, B {...}

@Bean
B myB() {new MyClass();}

@Autowired
A a;

//***************** a will inject failed(bean not found) if I delete this part
@Resource
MyClass myB;
//******************
```

I don't know why spring can find the "a".

I try to delete the `@Resource` part and it tell me bean not found, so spring use `@Resource` to do bean register?

I was thought only `@Bean` can do that(ya, I know xml can do that too), isn't it?

Comment: Hope this will help: https://www.sourceallies.com/2011/08/spring-injection-with-resource-and-autowired/

Comment: `@Resource` is used for injection not for registration

Comment: @Neo I know, this is why I ask this question, I don't know why `@Resource` part affect `@Autowired` part.

Comment: @user1686407 We don't have the same view of your application that you do. Why don't you reproduce it with some sample beans along with Tests and post it here if it is still not working?

Comment: @Neo I already provide all sample code, and the code work well, I just want to know why it work. Why `@Autowired A a;` need `@Resource MyClas myB` to inject.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting issue. I assume it happens because Spring uses some kind of optimization/lazy-creation during dependency injection.

This is only my assumption, but it's a quite good explanation for this issue:

When Spring find a `@bean` annotation, it doesn't immediately creates the bean, instead it only register it. (It's quite logical, beans could depend on each-other, so first it only tries to collect all of the registered beans, before it tries to actually create them). It also collects all the places where a bean is needed to be injected.

Then it tries to fullfill the injections in rounds. As long as it can fullfill at least one injection in a round, it continues the process.

When the beans are registered, they are registered by name and type which come from the annotation properties or from the method name and return type.
So there will be a bean registered with name `myB` with type `B`

At the first round it cannot find any beans for

```
@Autowired
A a;
```

so it skips it.

Then it tries to inject a bean into

```
@Resource
MyClass myB;
```

It can find a registered bean by name. Although the registered bean's type is not the same nor an extension of the required type, this bean was requested by name, and its actual instance type is not known yet, so - **I assume** - at this point Spring's injection logic trusts the programmers will, and it instantiates the bean by calling `myB()`, checks the actual type against the required type and because it matches, it happily injects the returned bean and **updates** the bean type in the registry with the actual type, which is `MyClass`.

There are no more injections, so it starts the next round:

Now, when it tries to inject

```
@Autowired
A a;
```

it still cannot find a bean by name, but it can find a bean where the registered type is an instance of `A`, so it can inject that bean too.

So, in short:
If you request a bean by name, then Spring will go and check if that bean fullfills the otherwise un-matching type requirements, but if you request a bean by type, it won't check the actual type of all of the available beans, instead raises and exception an let you refine the injection.